# define a variable as a result of a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a variable `date_from` that I can use in my queries:

```
define date_from = '01.11.2019';
```

Is it possible to define a new variable as a result of a query? The following statement doesn't work:

```
define month_from = (select month_yyyymm from t_calendar where date_orig = '&date_from');
```

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer and I don't want to go into PL/SQL.

Comment: In table `t_calendar`, what data type is `date_orig`? It seems it should be a **date**, but in the `select` statement you are comparing it to a string. That is a common, but very poor practice. This is unrelated to your question.

Comment: you should take a look at this https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/sqlplus-101-substitution-variables . However, I think what you want is not theoretically possible.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do what you want, directly. Note also that substitution variables (those created / assigned to with the `define` command and called with a leading `&`) are a SQL*Plus concept; they are pre-processed by the client software (in your case SQL Developer, which understands and honors most of, even though not all of, SQL*Plus).

You can do almost that, though, with the SQL*Plus option `new_value` to the `column` command. It goes something like this (not tested since you didn't provide sample data):

```
define date_from = '01.11.2019'
column month_yyyymm new_value month_from
select month_yyyymm from t_calendar where date_orig = '&date_from';
```

This is it - at this point the variable `month_from` stores the value of `month_yyyymm` returned by your query. Note that the first two commands are SQL*Plus (scripting) commands; only the last statement, the `select`, is ever seen by the database itself.